# Django: using zip as field name

Tags: python, django

One of the fields in our model is named `zip`.  It's for the zip code.  I now find that `zip` is also a built-in function.  A lot of code references `zip` and stuff seems to work fine, but it got me spooked.  Aside from bad coding practice, will this cause any problems, not just for `zip`, but for other built-in functions being used as field names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in having a field named `zip` since it's bound to the model namespace. You never refer to it directly and it doesn't shadow a built-in.

In other words, you always use a dot notation to get the field value: `my_instance.zip`.

Also see: [Django Coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/).

Comment: I was most surprised that `zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='')` was OK.  I would have expected Python to at least flag this.

Comment: @user2233706 you can run `pylint` or `pyflakes` checks on the models code and you won't see it marked as warning.